# evaluating grunt <%= yeoman.dist %> variable in static html file

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, build, gruntjs

I used angular yeoman generator and I have some static imaegs which depend on user locale

```
<img ng-src="images/<%= yeoman.dist %>.{{scopeVar}}.svg"/>
```

is it possible to parse also static html files of <%= yeoman.dist %> ? (or inject it somehow in a javascript as a variable in my app code)